# Is there a way to grant table-level permissions to only specific users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

My Database dbo.MyDb currently allows database-level access to a bunch of users.

However I now have a table in dbo.MyDb called "MyDbTable", which only specific users should be able to access. I don't want to DENY access to MyDb users because then we would have to deny access to new users manually every time a new user gets added. I want to only allow specific users (for example a guy named "user1") to access MyDbTable. No other user should be able to access MyDbTable.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to achieve this?

**Question 2:** If we can do only-allow, does that mean that only "user1" can make changes to that table from an app like a C#/NET backend app (by passing in his username and password along with the connectionstring)?

Comment: *"My Database dbo.MyDb"* Do you *really* have a database called `dbo.MyDB`? That would be very confusing if you have to use 3 part naming, especially against an object against the `dbo` schema. Using characters like `.` in an object name is never a good idea, and using `dbo` which as a prefix, when it's also the default schema for database objects, makes it even worse. You'd have to reference your table above as `[dbo.MyDb].dbo.MyDbTable`.

Comment: No it's just a silly example. Not real.

Answer (score 0):

- Add schema-level permissions to all existing schemas to the existing users.
- Drop the database-level permissions from the existing users.
- Test
- Make a new schema
- Move your new table to the new schema.
- Grant permissions on the new schema to only some users.

---

If you want to retain database-level permissions, you're going to need to DENY, because a database level permission is, in fact, a ***database level*** permission.